# Use a call Ajax to send an Array of string to mvc Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to get the values from the a table column, I put it in an array then send it to my controller. Something very strange happens, you'll see below :

Here is my JS code :

```
var result = [];

        $('td:nth-child(' + columnNbr + ')').each(function () {
            var t = $(this).html();
            result.push(t);
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTable", "Home")',
            dataType: "html",
            traditional: true,
            data: { values: result },
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
```

My Array "result" is well populated with the values I need.

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult UpdateTable(List<string> values)
{
    return View("index");
}
```

This returns a 500 internal error.
What's driving me crazy is this -> if I modify my JS from what I posted to this:

```
        //$('td:nth-child(' + columnNbr + ')').each(function () {
        //    var t = $(this).html();
        //    result.push(t);
        //});

        result.push("test1");
        result.push("test2");
```

The Ajax call works fine ... I checked the "typeof $.(this).html()" and all are strings!

I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: console.log your result array, could be the size of the array been posted.
Can you provide some of the test table data?

Comment: Here is my array : ["2015-06-16", "0", "0", "206000", "206000", "100", "0", "30558", "14,83", "14,83", "9", "19", "147", "0", "0", "88,04", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "87917", "-174422", "2849", "0", "0", "62,1", "<input type="button" value="Edit" id="4"> "]

Comment: The last item in the array is the problem (`"<input type="button" value="Edit" id="4"> "`). Exclude it

Comment: Instead of `{ values: result }` can you try - `JSON.stringify({ values: result })`, it worked for me that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change `var t = $(this).html();` to `var t = $(this).text();`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just use **[$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)**

```
var result = [];

$('td:nth-child('+columnNbr+')').each(function(){
    result.push($(this).text());
});

$.post('@Url.Action("UpdateTable", "Home")', {values: result});
```

Or if you need a **callback:**

```
$.post('@Url.Action("UpdateTable", "Home")', {values: result}, function(data){
    // what to do
});
```